# android Recyclerview delete all item one by one with slide animation

Tags: android

I have already know we can set item's animation by call RecyclerView's setItemAnimator method. After that, we can call notifyItemRangeRemoved to let all the items "fly away" together with animation, here is the remove code.

```
 int removedSize = dataCollection.size();
 dataCollection.clear();
 notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, removedSize);
```

However, my requirement is to remove item one by one and with some delay. I have try to use Timer + TimerTask + Handler classes to achieve it, however, each time I called notifyItemRemoved method, the RecyclerView will auto refill the item which have already disappear.

How can remove one item, and the blank place will not be replaced with another item directly?

Comment: How you are removing items from recyclerView..?

Comment: @SarithaG I put those remove code in recyclerview's adapter and call it in the activity

Comment: dataCollection.clear() means it will remove more items not only single item ..right?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **notifyDataSetChanged()** instead of **notifyItemRangeRemoved()**

Comment: But I'm trying to add animation to the item when it was removed, I have to call this method.

Comment: it's very strange. I try both methods in Activity and Adapter and it works properly...